# linear ode -order n

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

with the formula of solution of an order $n$ linear differential equation, calculate the exact solution of the differential equation:
$$y'''-3y'+2y=9 e^x, x>0$$

step 1: found the exact solution of the homogeneous equation associate: $$y'''-3y'+2y=0$$
We put $y(x)=e^{rx}$. Then, we inject it on the equation and we obtain: $$r^3e^{rx} - 3 r e^{rx} + 2 e^{rx}=0$$ so $$r^3-3r+2=0$$ who is an algebrig equation degre 3. My difficulties is to founf the exact solution of the equation.

Comment: What do you know about solving linear differential equations? Do you know how to solve $y'''-3y'+2y=0$?

Comment: I don't know what "Wu" means. I think your $e^rx$ should be $e^{rx}$. The are other typos and mathematical mistakes in what you have written. Please try again, taking a little more care.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I edit my messages.

Comment: Let's start with finding the 3rd derivative of $e^{rx}$. It isn't what you think it is.

Comment: I edit my first message. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Hint: $r^3-3r+2 = (r-1)^2(r+2)$.

Comment: Okay, there is three equations: $r_1=r_2=1$ and $r_3=-2$. So, the equation admits an independant system of solutions $\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ where $y_1(x)=e^x$ and $y_2(x)=xe^x$ and $y_3(x)=e^{-2x}$ so the general solution of the homogeneous equation is $$y(x)=c_1 e^x + c_2 x s^x + c_3 e^{-x}$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ and $c_3$ are three constants. But how we can found the solution of non-homogeneous equation? and the question is: found the solution to use the formula of order $n$ linear equation. Wat's this formula?

Comment: I don't know what the formula is, but I know how to solve the equation, and that should be good enough. The non-homogeneous part is $9e^x$. Ordinarily, that would suggest that the equation has a particular solution of the form $Ae^x$, and all you have to do is plug that in and find the value of $A$ that works. But that won't work for this question; since $e^x$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation, it can't possibly be a solution of the inhomogeneous equation. So instead you have to try $Axe^x$. But wait --- that can't work either, since (continued next comment) ...

Comment: ...since $xe^x$ is also a solution to the homogeneous equation. So you have to go up to $Ax^2e^x$. Try plugging that in, and you should find there is a value of $A$ that works.

Comment: Iknow the method of the variation of constant. We surch an particular solution to the forme $$y_p(x)=c_1(x)y_1(x)+c_2(x)y_2(x)+c_3(x)y_3(x)$$ but heare it's hard to do this beacause all the calculs... But this question is to use dirrectly the formula of exact solution of an order n non-homogeneous linear equation. What's this formula please?

Comment: As I told you already, I don't know "the formula", I only know the method. And the method I outlined has nothing to do with the method you write about. Try $y=Ax^2e^x$! Try it now! **Try it!**

Comment: so if i understand, we search and particular solution to the form $y_p(x)=Ax^2e^x$ then, we inject it on the edo, then we obtain the algerbic equation $-6xA+2Ax^2-9=0$ and her discriminant $\Delta$ is $\Delta=36A^2+72A$ how we can continue with this method?

Comment: No, if you substitute $y=Ax^2e^x$ into the ODE (what's an edo?), all the $x$-terms should go away, leaving you with an equation for $A$. Check your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

$$y'''-3y'+2y=9 e^x, x>0$$

We start by finding the homogeneous solution of:

$$y'''-3y'+2y=0$$

This gives us:

$$r^3 - 3r +2 = 0 \rightarrow (r-1)^2(r+2) = 0 \rightarrow  r_{1,2} = 1, r_3 = -2$$

So, we have a double root and a single root, so this yields:

$$y_h(x) = c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 e^x + c_3 xe^{x}$$

Now, because we have like results with our homogeneous solution, we have to choose a power for our particular solution of:

$$y_p = a x^2 e^x$$

Substituting this into the original ODE and equating sides leads to $a = \dfrac{3}{2}$.

Our final solution is:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 e^x + c_3 xe^{x} + \dfrac{3}{2} x^2 e^x$$

Comment: why you have  the choice $y_p=ax^2e^x$ please? and do you know the formula of solution of an order n linear equation?

Comment: If you look at our homogeneous solution, it already has a term of $e^x$. When we substitute the homogeneous solution in, we get $0 = 9e^x$, which is obviously incorrect. We need a particular solution that preserves a $9e^x$ term when substituted in. The approach is to choose a power that is one higher than our homogeneous. Since we already have a $c x e^x$ in the homogeneous, we choose one higher. See xample 9 at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx for a discussion. This is called the Method of Undetermined Coefficients. Regards

Comment: @grg: For the general nth order solution, we have see http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/4243/section52.pdf

Comment: @grg: Did this solve your issues?

Comment: Nice work! Needs a TU +1

Comment: Indeed, it was a good day spent on non-MSE matters, though a rainy, coldish day :-| $\;\;$ Hope your day's been great!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @grg: You are very welcome. Regards